# JQUERY event firing more than one time, when using delegate jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, jquery-delegate

I am using delegate jquery in my code, but when it fire some event it fire more than once, I know It is because i have bind the event of **optionclicked** class to the **boxes-main** class but i am in a situation that i have to bind these classes with each other, because the content that using **optionclicked** class is generating dynamically.
Is there ay solution to the problem so that event fire only once means it call  function once and show pop op once and post data once etc etc.

```
$('.boxes-main').on('click', '.optionclicked', function(){
    // do something
    var timetoclick = parseFloat($('#time').text());
    clearInterval(myCounter);
    var optionclicked = $(this).attr('data');
    var questionid = $(this).attr('data2');
    $.post("quesanscheck.php", {
        ans : optionclicked,
        id : questionid,
        time : timetoclick
    }, function(data, status) {
        alert(data);
        if(data == optionclicked)
        {
            //alert("dfad");
            setTimeout(function(){ rightans(); }, 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            // wrong ans red
            if(optionclicked == 'A')
            {
                document.getElementById('op1').style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById('op1').style.border = "0px";
            }
            if(optionclicked == 'B')
            {
                document.getElementById('op2').style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById('op2').style.border = "0px";
            }
            if(optionclicked == 'C')
            {
                document.getElementById('op3').style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById('op3').style.border = "0px";
            }
            if(optionclicked == 'D')
            {
                document.getElementById('op4').style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById('op4').style.border = "0px";
            }
            // right ans green
            if(data == 'A')
            {
                document.getElementById('op1').style.background = "green";
                document.getElementById('op1').style.color = "white";
                document.getElementById('op1').style.border = "0px";
            }
            if(data == 'B')
            {
                document.getElementById('op2').style.background = "green";
                document.getElementById('op2').style.color = "white";
                document.getElementById('op2').style.border = "0px";
            }
            if(data == 'C')
            {
                document.getElementById('op3').style.background = "green";
                document.getElementById('op3').style.color = "white";
                document.getElementById('op3').style.border = "0px";
            }
            if(data == 'D')
            {
                document.getElementById('op4').style.background = "green";
                document.getElementById('op4').style.color = "white";
                document.getElementById('op4').style.border = "0px";
            }
            setTimeout(function(){wrongans();}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on  _but when it fire some event it fire more than once_?

Comment: Please, reproduce this problem at JSFiddle.

Comment: Are your elements dynamically generated? if not then you don't need to use event delegation, or this might be the issue of event propagation.

Comment: this is basically a quiz page in which question and answer are loded dynamically, in boxes-main class and the option have the class name optionclicked and when i click on the option i want to fire the event but it fire more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I binded the click event with an variable named `event` and added the code

```
event.stopPropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
```

this one solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

try changing your code to:

```
$('.boxes-main').unbind('click').on('click', '.optionclicked', function(){
```

This removes all click events and adds a single event.

When I looked into this, the click event was firing twice, even though the click event was only added once.

I can't find the original SO post that helped me, but this worked for me.

Comment: Sory sir this doesnt work for me, the problem remains to be same

Answer (score 1):

try to use :

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

it stops the propogation